# ADODB.Recordset is returned as null from C# dll

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, adodb

I have created a C# dll to be used in MS Access. All works well on my dev machine. The C# dll has methods with return type as `ADODB.Recordset`. I have bound the returned recordset with MS Access forms and it works great on my development machine.

The problem is when I install the dll using an Installer on a different machine and run MS Access application. There is no error, but it always returns a `null` recordset. I have checked the references in MS Access and it is referencing my custom dll and Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.1 Library and there is no error in calling the C# methods. The other methods which return arrays and string are working fine, only methods with `ADODB.Recordset` as the return type have this problem.

My Development Machine: Windows Vista Service Pack Service Pack 2
Testing Machine: Windows 7 Professional Edition

The code for converting datatable to ADOD.Recordset in C# dll is as follows,

```
private Recordset ConvertToRecordset(DataTable inTable)
{
    ADODB.Recordset result = new ADODB.Recordset();
    result.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient;

    ADODB.Fields resultFields = result.Fields;
    System.Data.DataColumnCollection inColumns = inTable.Columns;

    foreach (DataColumn inColumn in inColumns)
    {
        resultFields.Append(inColumn.ColumnName
              , TranslateType(inColumn.DataType)
              , inColumn.MaxLength
              , inColumn.AllowDBNull ? ADODB.FieldAttributeEnum.adFldIsNullable :
                                         ADODB.FieldAttributeEnum.adFldUnspecified
              , null);
    }

    result.Open(System.Reflection.Missing.Value
              , System.Reflection.Missing.Value
              , ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic
              , ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic, 0);

    foreach (DataRow dr in inTable.Rows)
    {
        result.AddNew(System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                      System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < inColumns.Count; columnIndex++)
        {
            resultFields[columnIndex].Value = dr[columnIndex];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private DataTypeEnum TranslateType(Type columnType)
{
    switch (columnType.UnderlyingSystemType.ToString())
    {
        case "System.Boolean":
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adBoolean;

        case "System.Byte":
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adUnsignedTinyInt;

        case "System.Char":
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adChar;

        case "System.DateTime":
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate;

        case "System.Decimal":
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adCurrency;

        case "System.Double":
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDouble;

        case "System.Int16":
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adSmallInt;

        case "System.Int32":
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger;

        case "System.Int64":
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adBigInt;

        case "System.SByte":
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt;

        case "System.Single":
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adSingle;

        case "System.UInt16":
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adUnsignedSmallInt;

        case "System.UInt32":
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adUnsignedInt;

        case "System.UInt64":
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adUnsignedBigInt;

        case "System.String":
        default:
            return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar;
    }
}
```

I pass a DataTable to the above mentioned method like this and return the result:

```
ADODB.Recordset instanceRS = ConvertToRecordset(instancesDT);
return instanceRS;
```

One more time: the dataset returned on my development machine is fine and all the records are populated, but on testing machine it is always null. I have read somewhere that Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.1 Library for Windows 7 has to do something with it, but I can't find anything more specific. Is this right? How can I fix this?

Comment: very hard to tell what your DataSet is returning if you don't post the existing Code that you have..

Comment: fyi - there is no such thing as c sharp. The name of the language is C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this an ActiveX control?   If so are you sure your install program is registering the activex dll?

You need to register the activex dll on the local machine.

(For example a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=registering%20activex%20dll) shows [this](http://www.cknotes.com/?p=361))

Comment: yes it is a Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 2.1 Library. I have added the reference ADOD in the project where it is being converted. I have also added it in the Installer package named adod.dll.

Comment: @AdnanYaseen - this is not enough see the links provided.

Comment: Thank you for the link you have provided. If the ActiveX is already listed on the available references in MS Access References List, then will I still be needing to register it separately?

Comment: Yes, Thanks to you, It worked. You opened a doorway for me to search. Adding to your Solution, for anyone who is using Visual Studio installer then steps to registering ActiveX component is as follow,

1. Create a Setup project in Visual Studio 2008.
2. Add the ActiveX control DLL file into this Setup project.
3. Select the ActiveX DLL file in Solution Explorer and switch to Properties window.
4. Select vsdrfCOM for the Register property.

Reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winformssetup/thread/8ddd0fd2-e1dc-422c-86cc-366be8cf115b

Comment: @AdnanYaseen - remember it may be possible the local security policies will still block the registering.  (Esp. if you don't strongly sign your DLLs.)

Comment: Alright. I will look into that too. Right now it is working smoothly.